# Expect deep property to have any of multiple values

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, assertions

In [Chai assertion library](http://chaijs.com/), we can assert a deep property to exist and have a value:

```
expect(obj).to.have.deep.property("field1.field2", 1);
```

But, what if we need to **assert this property to have one of multiple values**? In this case, the test should pass if `obj` has a `field1.field2` property that has 0 or 1 or 2 value.

---

FYI, I need this to check that a `ESLint` plugin ships with a recommended rules configuration that has a "warning level" configured for every rule. [Warning level](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules) can be of 0, 1 or 2 values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.oneOf()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof):

```
expect(obj).to.have.deep.property('field1.field2').that.is.oneOf([ 0, 1, 2 ])
```

Or [`.within()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_within):

```
expect(obj).to.have.deep.property('field1.field2').that.is.within(0, 2)
```

Comment: That is just beautiful! Thanks so much. FYI, this is how it is applied in my case: https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/test/index.js#L31-L39.